# Pycharm does not show dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pycharm

When I'm reading a `csv` file using the pandas library, but when I print the head of the dataframe it doesn't show it as a dataframe but more like a list.

**This is the code I tipped:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Path/File')
print(df.head())
```

**The output looks like this**
[image: Output]

How do I get it show the data frame properly?

Comment: you need to specify the delimiter when you call `read_csv`, by default it uses `,` however your file appears to use `;`

Comment: pd.read_csv('Path/File',sep=';')

Comment: Actually that is a one-column, `object` type data frame!